# Using ArrayList to get two dimensional array data

Tags: java, recursion, multidimensional-array, arraylist, pass-by-reference

My input is a text document grid of 0's and 1's, which i then put into a two dimensional integer array.

The object for me is to "map" the 1's in the grid. I have to determine how many groups of 1's there are, how many each group has, and create a output text with the 1 groups labeled.

for example i receive the following in text:

```
1 0 1 0 0 1 0
1 1 1 0 1 1 0
1 0 0 0 1 0 0
0 0 1 0 0 0 1
0 0 1 1 1 1 1
```

I would have three total groups, then have to spit it out like:

```
1 0 1 0 0 2 0
1 1 1 0 2 2 0
1 0 0 0 2 0 0
0 0 3 0 0 0 3
0 0 3 3 3 3 3
```

As I'm doing my recursion, I created a two dimensional integer ArrayList to be expandable to groups and group members. I thought before that if i just changed all the "members" of the second group to 2's, then they should change in the original two dimensional Array because arrays are passed by reference.

Am I wrong? Let me know if any additional information needs to be given too.

Thanks in advance.

Edit: if use the ArrayList.contains() function, it seems i have the problem that its looking if it contains an actual "1" not if it contains int[][] array[0][1] for example.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds a lot like a Region Labelling algorithm to me. Maybe [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Connected-component_labeling) will help

Comment: Yep that's exactly what it is. It's the 8 connection version. I'm trying the best I can to get it down myself though, it'll help me learn a lot better i think.

Comment: Basically you have to start in the upper left corner and call the function for each of the 8 neighbors, if one of them is a match, you add it to a queue and look at its 8 neighbors later...when there are no further matches, you ++ the label and start with the next value in your original Array. There are probably lots of implementations Out there, but if you go through all the values one by one, its Not that hard to do yourself.